# Android looped at OnMAMCreate method

Tags: java, android, oncreate, mdm, intune

I try to incorporate Intune app protection policies into my native Android app. I follow instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-android. After I changed all classes into their MAM equivalents, my app looped at MAMApplication's onMAMCreate method. My main class derived from  MAMApplication class instead of Application class.

Below is my method:

```
@Override
public void onMAMCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    buildObjectGraphAndInject();

    setOrmProject(null);
    setOrmTemplate(null);

    //rest of method
}
```

And there is a message I got in debug console.

```
I/MAMInfo: Agent config file does not exist, will use test agent
I/MAMInfo: MAMInfo initialized. Debug=true, UseTestAgent=true, 
ManagedDialogDisabled=false, DeprecationDialogDisabled=false, 
PolicyRequired=false, MultiIdentityEnabled=false, 
FullBackupContent=true, UseDefaultEnrollment=false, 
ExceptionOnInit=false
I/MAMWERetryScheduler: task thread waiting for tasks.
I/MAMComponents: Not initializing MAM classes because the MDM package 
is not installed.
I/MAMComponents: Not initializing MAM classes because the MDM package 
is not installed.
```

Application do not throw an exception, it just looped at that method and stuck.
I read that MDM is not required to use MAM classes. Have anybody go any idea how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer here - I've only just starting using the SDK myself, but you need to call `super.onMAMCreate()` which in turn will call `super.onCreate()` internally.

Comment: Oh yeah. I already forgot about that question. Solution is to change all super.OnCreate() method calls to super.OnMAMCreate() method call. In whole application.

As an advice I suggest to use wrapping tool instead of adding and using SDK.